# jquery tablesorter custom order

Tags: jquery, python, tablesorter

I'm using this plugin on python.

Is it possible to make it order a column by a custom sequence?

In the `quality` column I can have only: 'low', 'mediocre', 'good', 'great' and I want ordered in that way (or reversed).

In the `Name` column I have (by the view) a custum order but I want to give the possibility to order alphabetically too and then return on the original order...

My `views.py`:

```
def aff_list(request):
    context_dict = {}
    lista_aff_a=[]
    lista_aff_s=[]
    for aff in Aff.objects.all():
        if aff.price=='luxury':
            lista_aff_a.append(aff)
        elif aff.price=='cheap':
            lista_aff_s.append(aff)
    lista_aff=lista_aff_a + lista_aff_s   #this way is ordered before lista_aff_a, then lista_aff_s

    context_dict['lista_aff'] = lista_aff

return render(request, 'aff_list.html', context_dict)
```

My `aff_list.html`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{% static "js/jquery-tablesorter/jquery.tablesorter.js" %}"></script>    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/tablesorter.css" %}" type="text/css" />
<script src="{% static "js/script-jquery.js" %}"></script>

...
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <table id="lista_aff" class="tablesorter table table-hover table table-bordered table table-condensed">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Quality</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        {% for aff in lista_aff %}
          <tr>
            <td>
                {{ aff.name }}
            </td>
            <td>
              {{ aff.quality }}                
            </td>
          </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

My `script-jquery`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#lista_aff").tablesorter();
});
```

Edit:

A last question:

I download the file and decompressed in `static/js`, then I write in the head of my template:

```
<link href="{% static "js/tablesorter-master/css/theme-blue.css" %}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/dashboard.css" %}">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{% static "js/tablesorter-master/js/jquery.tablesorter.js" %}">
```

To make they work I must change the name of the themes from `theme.#` to `theme-#` and add in my `script-jquery.js`:

```
theme : 'blue',
```

Just 'blue', not 'theme-blue'.
It works but maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Are you trying to order the column on the server or client side?

Comment: You need to add a parser - [see documentation](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-parsers.html).

Comment: Thank you. And for the 'name' column? Is it possible to 'reset'  the order and see the initial one?

Comment: The original version of tablesorter does not have a reset method built-in. You can check out my [fork of tablesorter](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html) which has a [`sortReset` option](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html#sortreset) which will reset the sort on the third click.

Comment: Good, thank you! I solved the problems but I edit my question with another doubt (little, I promise). And if you want you can write an answer so I will accept it. And compliments for your work!

Comment: Go ahead and add the solution you used, you need to repo more than me ;)

Comment: And yes, just use "blue" as the theme value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the fork suggested in the comment I solved my problems in this way:

My `script-jquery`:

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
  id: 'quality',
  is: function(s) {
    // return false so this parser is not auto detected
    return false;
  },
  format: function(s) {
    // format your data for normalization
    return s.toLowerCase().replace(/great/,0).replace(/good/,1
        ).replace(/mediocre/,2).replace(/low/,3);
  }, 
  // set type, either numeric or text
  type: 'numeric'
});

$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#lista_Aff").tablesorter({    
    theme : 'blue',
    sortReset   : true,
    headers: { 1: { sorter: 'quality' } }
  });

});
```